# How to find the inscribed and circumscribed circles from convex region?

Tags: geometry, circles, bezier-curve, convex-hulls

Let $\mathbf{P}(t)$ be a piecewise bezier curve of degree $p$, which defines a jordan curve in the plane such the interior region $D$ is convex.

**Question:** How can I find the external $C_e$ and internal $C_i$ circles by using $\mathbf{P}$ ?

As example, if $\mathbf{P}$ defines a triangle, then bellow we have the internal and external circles to this triangle respectively.

[image: Inscribed-Circumscribed]

**Note 1:** $p = 1$ tells $D$ is a polygon shape

**Note 2:** The external circle is the circle with minimum area such

- $\mathbf{P}(t) \in \overline{D}_{e} \ \ \ \ \forall t$

**Note 3:** The internal circle is the circle with maximum area such

- $\mathbf{P}(t) \notin D_{i} \ \ \ \ \forall t$
- $D \cap D_{i} \ne \emptyset $

**Note 4:** $D$ is a open set